# lie algebra bundle and underlying vector bundle

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, cohomology, vector-bundles, torsors

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over a field $k$. Let $E$ be a $G$-bundle, then we can form the adjoint bundle $ad(E)$ which is a Lie algebra bundle over $k$.
As a vector bundle it is trivial, but is there a criterion to know when it is trivial as a Lie algebra bundle?

More generally the same question could be asked over a base scheme $S$ and for a $G$-torsor $E$ such that $ad(E)$ is a trivial vector bundle over $S$.

Comment: Why is it trivial?